# A difficulty in understanding a step in a solution.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

Here is the solution:

[image]

But I could not understand how the last term in the fourth line came from the line before it, could anyone explain this for me please?

**EDIT:**
I have highlighted the problem:

[image]

Comment: The expression in brackets is not part of $\ln n$.

Comment: Could you be kind enough to tell us what $c_n$ and $a_n$ denote ? (I known we can guess.)

Comment: yes it is not part @Chrystomath this is why I am confused why he multiplied the n

Comment: $c_{n} = n \ln n $@YvesDaoust

Comment: @YvesDaoust  I have edited the problem

Comment: I have clarified my question sorry @Chrystomath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{ln}n\frac{4n^2+5n}{4n^2+8n+4} &= \operatorname{ln}n\frac{4n^2+5n}{4n^2+8n+4} - \operatorname{ln}n + \operatorname{ln} n \\
&= \operatorname{ln}n\left(\frac{4n^2+5n}{4n^2+8n+4} - 1\right) + \operatorname{ln}n
\end{align*}

---

Edit: For the new edited question note that

$$n\operatorname{ln}n\frac{4n+5}{4n^2+8n+4} = \operatorname{ln}n\frac{4n^2+5n}{4n^2+8n+4}$$

This is the same situation as $$xy\frac{a}{b} = y\frac{xa}{b}$$

Comment: please read the question carefully

Comment: I have clarified my question sorry

Comment: @hopefully See the edited answer above

Comment: another small question taking limit as n tends to infinity at the last line  ..... what happens to the term $\ln n $...... it was multiplied by 0 after taking the limit ..... is the effect of a polynomial function more rapid than the effect of the \ln function?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as in $xy = x(y-1)+x$. Here $x=\ln n$ and $y$ is the fraction.

Comment: please read  the question carefully

Comment: I have clarified my question sorry

Comment: Ah, the third line ... I was wondering why you ask about such an easy thing :D